# Can I use Juju/MAAS on VPSes?

Tags: server, juju, maas

I was wondering if I can setup MAAS on set of VPSes and manage them with Juju but I see no way to manualy install MAAS Node (is it even possible?). I know I'm missing core point in whole MAAS-game by installing Node manualy but I cannot run Ubuntu installation on my VPSes and I cannot run DHCP server, on provider's infrastructure.

Or is there another way to use Juju with VPSes? Or maybe it will be possible in future with Juju 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

Juju requires a real cloud to work which means you can't use it for most VPSes. For VPSs that have an API someone would need to write a provider for it so Juju can use it.

If anyone is interested in working on "scaling Juju down" here are some getting started pointers, but as of now the project is focused on scaling up:

- https://juju.ubuntu.com/the-juju-unprovider/

For 2.0 there *might* be a way to leverage the local provider and docker.io to make it easy to shoot Juju containers over to a VPS, but there hasn't been much discussion on that yet.